# Can WordPress comments have titles and taxonomy?

Tags: comments

I have a business directory theme that has a custom post-type for businesses and replaces WordPress comments with its own commenting feature called reviews.

I was wondering if it is possible to customize comments to have a taxonomy, title and permalink.

Meaning I can organize comments in categories and tags?

And it could have a link like this:

> example.com/baskin-robins-icecream/reviews/my-review-of-baskin-robins

The link would take them to the post and comment area.

If I want some of this functionality? What are some things I need to consider and look into?

Comment: What exactly is the "commenting feature called reviews"? If you plan to extend it, it is hard to guess what should you do exactly, as we don't know what the feature is exactly.

If you want to build the commenting system from scratch, you can create another custom post type for comments and move creating/editing the posts to front-end. It is obviously quite heavy way how to do it, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Theoretically.

1. Comments do *not* have title field in a database. However they have meta natively, so quick [`add_comment_meta()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_comment_meta/) can get you title–like custom field.
2. Comments have links ([`get_comment_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_comment_link/)), but they are heavily based on context of singular post displaying them. Displaying comments by themselves with their own URLs structure would take some creative rewrite effort.
3. I can't say about level of effort it would take for taxonomies to work with comments, but it's definitely not a natively supported object type for them.

In a nutshell you are going to be trying pretty hard to make comments behave like a custom post type and they **just aren't** that. Although it would make sense, but WordPress, backwards compatibility, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Any updates regarding taxonomy for comments?

I know it's not a native WordPress functionality, but to make something like this https://ebomounao.com.br/7247/geladeira-consul-crd37-cycle-defrost-duplex-334-litros-e-bom to work with WordPress I'll have to either work with a new custom-post-type or extend comments functionalities.

I like the idea of taxonomies for comments because I could get the most out of WooCommerce reviews...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253074)